# Prolog Question - How to generate sublists of a given length

Tags: prolog, backtracking

I want to generate all the sublists of a given list with the given property that they have a certain length mentioned as argument and also they have as a containing element a given element which is passed as a parameter. I have managed to do this but with the help of two predicates, and in terms of optimality is very slow:

```
sublist([], []).
sublist([A|T], [A|L]):-
    sublist(T, L).
sublist(T, [_|L]):-
    sublist(T, L).

choose(T, L):-
    sublist(T, L),
    (dimension(2, T); dimension(1, T)),
    belongs(f, T).
```

In here I would like to return through the `T` parameter of the `choose` predicate all the sublists of the L list which have the dimension 2 or 1 and which contains the `f` element. 
The predicates `dimension` and `member` has the same usage as the predefined predicates `length`, respectively `member`.
Can you please tell me how to incorporate this two conditions within the `sublist` predicate so that the program builds only those particular sublists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following builds subsequences of length `MinLen =< Len =< MaxLen`. I've no idea why you renamed `length` and `member`, so I'm going to use the originals. `sublist/4` calls your `sublist/2`.

```
sublist(Sub,List,MinLen,MaxLen) :-
    between(MinLen,MaxLen,Len),
    length(Sub,Len),
    sublist(Sub,List).
```

Note that `length` is called on two variables, so you get an [iterative deepening search](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Search_techniques). `choose/2` can now be defined as

```
choose(Sub,List) :-
    sublist(Sub,List,1,2),
    member(f,Sub).
```

This is the clean solution. If it's is not fast enough, then roll all the conditions into one predicate:

```
choose(Sub,List),
    (Sub = [f] ; Sub = [f,_] ; Sub = [_,f]),
    sublist(Sub,List).
```